# How to add width property to the canvas in flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I need to add the width property to the canvas .By traceing the value iam geting  its value as zero though it contain images and has a width.

//code of adding 5 canvases to the main canvas
public function addcanvas(canarr:Array):void
        {

```
        var can_arr:Array=new Array();
        can_arr=canarr;
        for(var c:int=0;c<can_arr.length;c++)
        {

            canvasA=new Canvas();
            canvasA.id="canvasA";
            trace("ccc:"+c);
            canvasA.x=(c*10)+10;
            canvasA.y=0;2
            this.addChild(canvasA);

        }
                   trace("canvasA.width:  "+canvasA.width);
          }
```

and next i will add images into each canvas

//`enter code here`
public function ClubCards(imgarr:Array):void
    {
                var Gimg_arr:Array = new Array();
                Gimg_arr =imgarr;

```
            for(var j:int=0;j < Gimg_arr.length;j++)
            {
                myimage1 = new Image();
                myimage1.x=0+(j*20);
                myimage1.y=40;
                           myimage1.source=gameModule.getStyle(Gimg_arr[j].toString());

                GroupingImageListeners(myimage1);

                canvasA.addChild(myimage1);

            trace("canvasA.width:  "+canvasA.width );
        }
```

iam unable to know the width of the canvas which has images in it . can u please help me out.how can i get that canvas width
Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess you want to get the max size of the images that added to canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add a comment, so I will add an answer saying this code should be triggered by a call to the updateDisplayList method (during the appropriate phase of the flex component life-cycle). I would suggest reading and understanding this update cycle before doing any further Flex development (it will save you a lot of time in the long-run).

More info can be found here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html

*UPDATE*

Since you mentioned Canvas, I updated the link to point to the 3.x version of the article

Comment: Thank u for your valuable answer @drkstr1

Comment: @user1996253 Just to clarify something, not all of that code should go in updateDisplay list, only the sizing and positioning. You would addChild in the createChildren() phase, and most likely want to set the image source in commitProperties(). One thing you dont want to do is put code in updateDisplay list that affects the measured size (which may be the case after taking a closer look at your code). Doing so would cause it to run through the update cycle twice, which is inefficient. The important takeaway is that measurement ad updates are phased, not instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

You did not make your canvas invalidate its size. Without an order to redraw, I don't think you'll get the correct size. Without Event.RENDER dispatched your component will not calculate its size.

Maybe you should try:

```
canvas.invalidateSize();
```

before accessing its width and see the result. This should make your canvas call its method measure() and calculate its size.